# Обучение Delphi. Работа со строкой

Tags: delphi, строки

Всем привет! Написал программу, которая преобразует введенную строку, удалив из нее все буквы.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
txt, Sum: string;
 i, num: Integer;
begin
memo1.Lines.Clear;
  txt:=Edit1.Text;
 for i:= 1 to Length(txt) do
    begin
     if TryStrToInt(txt[i], num) then 
      begin
      Sum:=sum+IntToStr(num);

      end;
 end;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(sum);
 end;

end.
```

На что мне нужно заменить `IntToStr`, чтобы удалялись не буквы, а цифры? Где можно посмотреть  полный список подобных операторов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или заменить вашу проверку на:

```
if txt[i] not in ['0'..'9'] then 
  begin
      Sum:=sum+txt[i];
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно изменить условие в этом коде так:

```
if Not TryStrToInt(txt[i], num) then
     Sum:=sum+txt[i];
```

P.S. Begin...End на условии можно опустить, да и на цикле тоже.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот Вам ссылка](http://delphibasics.ru/) где описано не мало функций